# corecrt_memcpy_s.h: error C2065: 'errno': undeclared identifier

Tags: windows, visual-c++, github-actions, libuv

When trying to compile libuv for Windows using cl.exe on GitHub Actions we get this error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\corecrt_memcpy_s.h(77):
error C2065: 'errno': undeclared identifier
```

The full output is [here](https://github.com/kroggen/libuv/runs/1578559992?check_suite_focus=true)

This is the start of the [build script](https://github.com/kroggen/libuv/blob/build/.github/workflows/build.yml):

```yaml
    - name: build x64
      shell: cmd
      run: |
        call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
        cl /c /MT -Iinclude -Iinclude\uv -Isrc -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 ${{ env.SOURCES }}
```

I also tried without the `/MT` but the result is the same.

It appears that there is nothing related to errors with this `corecrt_memcpy_s.h` (at the moment of posting) so this question can be useful to others.

Comment: Does compiling it locally work?

Comment: I am not a Windows guy. I have an old Windows 7 machine here but dev tools not good and I wanted a reproducible way to compile libuv. Maybe I will give up this Windows mess and go back to cross-compilation